# What is the best way to get the values of each TableView Cell to send back to the server?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I am writing a new app in swift and I'm new to swift was well.

I have setup each of the cells in the tableView so they ask for a specific type of answer.  Things like multiple choice, Yes/No, Quantity and Photo. I have the answers in the cells as I can log them out when we make changes to things like the yes/no questions. But my problem is I need to get each question, its type and the response the user gives to serialize in JSON to send back  What is the best way for me to get this data so I can send it?

Thanks in advance for everyones help

Answer (score 1):

**Just a short overview, So you get your answer**

UITableView is highly optimized, and thus only keep On-screen visible rows in memory. Now, All rows Cells are cached in Pool and are reused and not regenerated. Whenever, user scrolls the UITableView, it adds the just-hidden rows in Pool and reuses them for next to be visible rows.

**So, now, coming to your answer**

UITableViewCells won't save user selected values

Best solution will be to pro-actively save user selected response in NSMutableDictionary for each index.

For eg., if user taps on yes, then save that in datasource on tap event and keep updating your cell view in

```
tableView cellForRowAtIndexpath
```

And send the same saved data to server.